# SQL request for query in every week/month even if no record exist

Tags: mysql, count

I  am using MySQL and I have a hard time to get the count per month including months with no records.

This is my table "Plays":

```
idplay    idplayer    day
------    --------    ---
1             26        17-11-2015
2             37        22-12-2015
3             65        24-04-2016
4             12        16-05-2016
5             37        17-05-2016
6             37        30-05-2016
7             14        30-06-2016
```

I want to get the number of times the player "37" has played in every month the last 6 month and get 0 when he has not played.

Somthing like this:

```
Month          Playtimes
----           -------
11-2015             0
12-2015             1
01-2016             0
02-2016             0
03-2016             0
04-2016             0
05-2016             5
```

Comment: It is somewhat non trivial to handle this because you need data somewhere for all the months.  One nice option would be for you to create a table containing the months and years covering you data.  Then join to the table above.

Answer (score 3):

For this to work, as suggested in the comments, I've created a new relation that simple lists the months (I've used the values over the past year).

It then uses a left outer join to match these to the months in the `Plays` table, corresponding only to the plays matching your designated player.

A query is then used to count up these rows, with nulls attributed to zero.

The create statement is here;

```
CREATE TABLE Months (day DATE);
INSERT INTO Months VALUES
('2015.11.1'),('2015.12.1'),('2016.1.1'),
('2016.2.1'), ('2016.2.1'), ('2016.3.1'),
('2016.4.1'), ('2016.5.1'), ('2016.6.1'),
('2016.7.1'), ('2016.8.1'), ('2016.9.1'),
('2016.10.1'), ('2016.11.1');
```

And the following query to show the games per month, in the last 6 months, by player 37 is here

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(M.day,'%Y-%m') AS Month, COUNT(idPlayer) AS Playtimes
FROM Months M
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
           FROM Plays
           WHERE Plays.idPlayer = 37) P
ON MONTH(M.day) = MONTH(P.day) 
AND YEAR(M.day) = YEAR(P.day)
WHERE M.day BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 Month) 
    AND NOW() 
GROUP BY M.day;
```

I've created it into an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad0890/56) as well here which works and produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION DATEPART does not exist :/

Comment: Dont worry. See new version ive swapped that out

Comment: this returns only months with records . other months arn't included

Comment: @AymenYasser See new solution

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(day, '%c-%Y') Month, COUNT(day) Playtimes
FROM Plays 
WHERE idplayer = 37 AND day BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND NOW()
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(day, '%c-%Y')
```

Comment: This doesn't find the number of plays per month - but the number of plays per day surely

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'day' in 'field list'

Comment: Yeah sorry, fixed! Thanks for pointing it out @davidhood2. I have tested it out, this works perfectly fine!

Comment: @AymenYasser column ``day`` is from your illustrated columns, please check if you have it in your table structure.

Comment: @designcise bthis returns only months with records . other months arn't included

Comment: @AymenYasser in that case please see Tim Biegeleisen's suggestion!